# How to remove duplicates values from a div that acts like a select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am selecting category(using checkbox) and then based on category I am getting sub category, If I select first category getting 2 rows(example), if I deselect then getting same rows once again is there anything to remove duplicates from a div.

I am using search function from jQuery but not getting correct non duplicate values.

This is the where subcategory details will append one by one

```js
var expanded = false;

function showCheckboxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.getElementById("checkboxes");
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
}
$('.search-box').on("change", function(e) {

  var inputVal1 = $(this).val();
  var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
  var lclObj = JSON.parse(cars);
  for (var i = 0; i < lclObj.length; i++) {

    var lclSubCategory = lclObj[i];

    $('#checkboxes').append("<input type='checkbox' id='chkBox' value=" + lclSubCategory + ">" + lclSubCategory + "<br>");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group search-box">
  <label>Category:</label>
  <select class="form-control">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="multiselect col-sm-6">
  <label>Sub Category:</label>
  <div class="selectBox form-group" onclick="showCheckboxes()">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option value="">Select an option</option>
    </select>
    <div class="overSelect"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="checkboxes"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code in the question doesn't seem related to your description at all; there's no checkboxes, and there's no 'duplicate' div elements? Please add a more representative example of the problem to the question.

Comment: Thank you for editing. Note that I fixed the syntax issues in the snippet - however it's still not clear exactly what you're trying to do, or what the problem is

Comment: getting still error in above code if you fix then i can show.

Comment: It's your job to post a good question with code and description that replicates your problem. Not ours to make your question and to answer it. Please share the minimum amount of code required that replicates your specific problem.

Comment: yes bro but i have only this much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$('div').empty()` before append on it.

Comment: but i need previous values.

Comment: if i $('div').empty() do this one , Then Previously selected checkbox in sub category will be destroyed.

Comment: can you show the full code. Your code snippet is not clear

Comment: I'd suggest deleting this answer as it doesn't address the issue at all